# access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" when calling from another Thread

Tags: java

I got some java fxml application and im sending some http request with apache httpclient. When I'm calling my function from DesignController (after clicking some layout element) everything works ok:

```
@FXML
public void clickarea(MouseEvent event) {
    myFunction();
}
```

but when i want to call it from my mail application class (i use runLater() becouse without it i got an exeption that i can modify UI from other thread):

```
Platform.runLater(() -> {
DesignController dc = (DesignController) fxmlLoader.getController();
        dc.myFunction();
    });
```

I get some error: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission"....
When I check a console I can see:

```
network: Connecting http://149.126.77.9:80/ with proxy=DIRECT
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 503 for URL: http://149.126.77.9:80/crossdomain.xml
```

I dont know why same function works diffrent in these cases. Why is it checking crossdomain file only when I call my function from main thread?

I was trying to turn off checking for this file or set that 503 is not an error code but I dont know how.

I also noticed that when i call this funtion from main thread i can see in console: network: Connecting http://IP..... but when i call it from DesignController instead of IP i can see domain

Answer (score 0):

fixed:

```
AccessController.doPrivileged(
    new PrivilegedAction<String>() {
        public String run() {
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            myFunction();
        });
        return null;
        }
    }
);
```